# Check if any is marker is visible

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a Google Maps with multiple markers working just fine. The Google Maps has a filter that sets the marker on `marker.setVisible(false);` if the marker doesn't meet de requirements of the filter.

The only thing I need is a check if there is a marker visible, it doesn't matter if the marker is in the view or not. So I can show in case all the markers has `setVisible(false)` a div with the text 'No markers available'.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.getVisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(!marker.getVisible()){
         document.getElementById('divId').value = 'No marker available';
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if there is a single marker. In my situation there are multiple markers. For example 9/10 markers are visible then the if statement returns true instant of false.